# Run a script and get each lines result

Tags: scala

I want to write a simple Scala script that runs some methods that are defined in another file.

Each line that runs this method requires information that won't be available until runtime. For simplicity sakes, I want to abstract that portion out.

Thus, I want to use Currying to get the result of each line in the script, then run the result again with the extra data.

```
object TestUtil {
    // "control" is not known until runtime
    def someTestMethod(x: Int, y: Int)(control: Boolean): Boolean = {
        if (control) {
            assert(x == y)
            x == y
        } else {
            assert(x > y)
            x > y
        }
    }
}
```

someTestMethod is defined in my primary codebase.

```
// testScript.sc
import <whateverpath>.TestUtil

TestUtil.someTestMethod(2,1)
TestUtil.someTestMethod(5,5)
```

Each line should return a function, that I need to rerun with a Boolean.

```
val control: Boolean = true
List[(Boolean) -> Boolean) testFuncs = runFile("testScript.sc")
testFuncs.foreach(_(control)) // Run all the functions that testScripts defined
```

(Sorry if this is a weird example, it's the simplest thing I can think of)

So far I have figured out how to parse the script, and get the Tree. However at that point I can't figure out how to execute each individual tree object and get the result. This is basically where I'm stuck!

```
val settings = new scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerSettings(println)
settings.usejavacp.value = true
settings.nc.value = true

val interpreter: IMain = new IMain(settings)
val treeResult: Option[List[Tree]] = interpreter.parse(
  """true
    | 5+14""".stripMargin)
treeResult.get.foreach((tree: Tree) => println(tree))
```

the result of which is

> true
>
> 5.$plus(14)

where 5 + 14 has not been evaluated, and I can't figure out how, or if this is even a worthwhile route to pursure

Answer (score 0):

In the worst case you could `toString` your modified tree and then call `interpreter.interpret`:

```
val results = treeResult.get.map { tree: Tree => interpreter.interpret(tree.toString) }
```

It seems like it would be better to have the other file evaluate to something that can then be interpreted passing `control` (e.g. using the scalaz Reader Monad and for/yield syntax). But I assume you have good reasons for wanting to do this via an extra scala interpreter.